# Trouble inserting variables into SQL database using PHP

Tags: php, sql, variables

I need to save information from an HTML document to an SQL database using PHP. However, I have a problem with the concatenation of variables. This is what I have so far:

```
$requete= $sql->prepare"(INSERT INTO personnes (name,surname,street,city,country) 
                         VALUES". "("$name.$surname.$street.$city.$country."))";
```

So far, this is the only part posing problems, as the rest of the code is working when I debut. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This code has many issues. You don't want to concatenate to start with. You want each value to be inserted into the DB, right? This also is note the correct way to use prepared statements. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php or http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php I think this also should be throwing a 500.

Comment: You need to learn basic PHP syntax, and how to not make yourself vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: If there were a most common comment whenever someone does this it's "sql injection attacks".  It makes me wonder why it's not more obvious that this is the wrong way of doing things.  Like, PHP should deprecate its usage or disallow it altogether.  Somehow.

Comment: Some kind of IDE static code analysis warning? Surprised someone hasn't built this already with the prevalence of it.

Answer (score 0):

use `,` for separating values. `.` (DOT) is use for concatenating strings.

```
$requete= $sql->prepare("INSERT INTO personnes (name,surname,street,city,country) 
        VALUES ('$name','$surname','$street','$city','$country')");
```

this is your query. You need to bind parameter too.

`$sql->bind_param($name,$surname,$street,$city,$country);`

For more information [read](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: Might be worth mentioning SQL injection flaws in this statement too, and the use of prepared statements to overcome this

Comment: You corrected other things here as well (SQL strings need quotes, `prepare` is a function). Prepared statement still being used incorrectly though.

Comment: yep. You are right. this is vulnerable to sql injections. I am just guiding that whats wrong in current code.

Answer (score -2):

Use `?` as values and bind your values to the query. I actually cannot give you an example.

This is also described in the [**PHP documentation**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php):

You can use parameter binding with the mysqli Statement Object how it is showing in the first example for Object oriented style of the [Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.prepare.php):

**Example #1 Object oriented style**

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'world');

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO CountryLanguage VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('sssd', $code, $language, $official, $percent);

$code = 'DEU';
$language = 'Bavarian';
$official = "F";
$percent = 11.2;

/* execute prepared statement */
$stmt->execute();

printf("%d Row inserted.\n", $stmt->affected_rows);

/* close statement and connection */
$stmt->close();

/* Clean up table CountryLanguage */
$mysqli->query("DELETE FROM CountryLanguage WHERE Language='Bavarian'");
printf("%d Row deleted.\n", $mysqli->affected_rows);

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

And also as procedual style as it described in the second example.

**Example #2 Procedural style**

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$city = "Amersfoort";

/* create a prepared statement */
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($link);
if (mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, 'SELECT District FROM City WHERE Name=?')) {

    /* bind parameters for markers */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $city);

    /* execute query */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    /* bind result variables */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $district);

    /* fetch value */
    mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);

    printf("%s is in district %s\n", $city, $district);

    /* close statement */
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}

/* close connection */
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```